# Is there a way to copy code from eclipse including ine numbers

Tags: eclipse, copy, line-numbers

I am writing a little bit of documentation and code explanation. I would like to copy code from eclipse including line numbers, so that it becomes easier to reference the code in the text.

Is there any way to do this in eclipse or some other IDE, editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Eclipse 3.4 and bug 19602](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19602#c68), you will print the line numbers if you have activated them on the Eclipse editor.

[alt text http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/7605/eclipseshowlines.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/7605/eclipseshowlines.png)

Printing a source will give you:

[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/9899/eclipseprint.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/9899/eclipseprint.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by printing a PDF of source file, then copying source with line numbers from the PDF document.

It works for me with eclipse PDT + CutePDF, it should also work with Acrobat PDF printer

Comment: Fantastic, works with PDFCreator. It does not preserve indentation, when i paste it into my editor but that is only a minor issue.

Comment: I haven't noticed that, it could be due to PDF cell formatting... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Another not-so-clean work-around to achieve this. This is specific to the [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plug-in.

3 steps to follow:

1. Delete the piece of code you need to copy and save the source file.
2. Right click the file and chose option Team -> Create Patch.. and save it to a file, say copy.patch
3. Undo (Ctrl + Z) the changes  to revert the deletion done in step 1 and save the source file again.

Open the patch file and use the contents.

This also includes the file-name (if desired) along with the line number and retains the indentation.