# Copy/Pasting from Eclipse to Word with Line numbers?

Tags: java, eclipse, copy, paste

I've been trying to copy-paste my source code for a few java classes from eclipse/ADT to MS Word, and the formatting is retained. But I'm unable to copy the line numbers next to each line of code, and even if I check `Show Line Numbers` under `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors`, it still doesn't paste.

What am I missing? (I searched around for some time but haven't found anything... if there's anything on SO that addresses this, I haven't seen it, sorry)

Comment: Look at [this stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873201/is-there-a-way-to-copy-code-from-eclipse-including-ine-numbers/6754553#6754553).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your eclipse version, lines numbers will be added or not, if you activated the 'Show line numbers' option.

If it doesn't work with your eclipse version, there is a simple solution :

- expand all your code in your file (Ctrl+Numpad_Multiply),
- select everything (Ctrl+A),
- copy & paste in your new Word document,
- in 'Page Layout', set 'Line Numbers' to 'Continuous'.

Comment: Thank you, but the continuous line number solution doesn't work well for me since the document I'm copying the code to doesn't just have code. So this would add line numbers to regular text as well. I've tried on two different versions of eclipse (ADT, and Juno) and it hasn't' worked for either.