# How to print specific lines of source code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, printing, ide

For example, I want to print my source code from line 526 - 561 and I also want the **line numbers to appear.**

Comment: basically you want this functionality somewhere in eclipse , AFAIK , its not there

Comment: What happens, after selecting lines 526 - 561, when in the print dialog you check "print selection?"

Comment: Thats how i would expect it to work if the line numbers are shown in the editor it should work.

Comment: Step 1: print out the lines you want. Step 2: take an ink pen, and manually write in line numbers (although you usually only need one every 10 lines or so).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2873363/1324631 appears to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

[Is there a way to copy code from eclipse including ine numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873201/is-there-a-way-to-copy-code-from-eclipse-including-ine-numbers)

I would say you just have your line numbers displayed in eclipse (see above question on howto) then mark lines 526-661 and press Ctrl+P, select "Print Selection" and see what happens. (I currently realy dont have ANY possibility to test it myself, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

For a short snippet of code like the OP's 36 lines, I'll usually just copy the code from Eclipse, paste it into [Geany](https://www.geany.org/Main/About) (which runs in Linux, OSX, and Windows), and print it from there. With Geany set to show and print line numbers, of course.